# Apache HTTPD web server send value in session

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I have a client specific vanity URL hosted on web server from where it should carry a client identifier in HTTP request to the target URL.

As Apache web server is not jsp/servlet like container, is there a way to achieve?

I dont want to pass as query string.

Comment: Do you control the client? Or the link they'll follow?

Comment: something.com/clientA redirects to something.com/auth  and client id should be passed in session attribute or hidden attribute should not come in as query string.   both are controlled by us